# When I assign a signal with x in verilog, what happend in circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, verilog, verilator

I want to know what happen in circuit if I `assign wire_a = 2'bx1`.

Actually I used a module `MuxKeyWithDefault`, I want to use a key with signal `x`, so I write down my code as follows:

```
MuxKeyWithDefault #(2, 17, 32) mux_dnpc (npc,{fun7,fun3,op_code}, snpc,{
                          17'bxxxxxxxxxx1101111, pc + imm, 
                          17'bxxxxxxx0001100111, (src1_data + imm)&~1
                      });
```

This code can compair `{fun7,fun3,op_code}` with key `17'bxxxxxxxxxx1101111` and `17'bxxxxxxx0001100111`. If key is hitted in `key_list`, `npc` will be assgin by values as follows.

But I fund that the first `key` in `key_list` only can be paird when `x=0`. In other words, `17'b11111111111101111` cannot be hitted in `key_list`.

So I write down the signal `test`, and I have simulated it in verilator and I found that `x` comes to `0` in wave.

I want to know why and is it possible to assign a signal with uncertain value like `x` ?

And this is the minimal example that you can run by yourself to observe the signal :

```vhdl
module EXU(
        input clk,
        input rst,
        input [31:0]inst,
        output [31:0] pc
    );
    
    wire [6:0] op_code = inst[6:0];
    wire [2:0] fun3 = inst[14:12];
    wire [6:0] fun7 = inst[31:25];

    MuxKeyWithDefault #(2, 17, 32) mux_dnpc (pc,{fun7,fun3,op_code}, 32'b0,{
                          17'bxxxxxxxxxx1101111, 32'b1, 
                          17'bxxxxxxx0001100111, 32'd2,
                      });

endmodule

module MuxKeyWithDefault #(NR_KEY = 2, KEY_LEN = 1, DATA_LEN = 1) (
  output [DATA_LEN-1:0] out,
  input [KEY_LEN-1:0] key,
  input [DATA_LEN-1:0] default_out,
  input [NR_KEY*(KEY_LEN + DATA_LEN)-1:0] lut
);
  MuxKeyInternal #(NR_KEY, KEY_LEN, DATA_LEN, 1) i0 (out, key, default_out, lut);
endmodule

module MuxKeyInternal #(NR_KEY = 2, KEY_LEN = 1, DATA_LEN = 1, HAS_DEFAULT = 0) (
  output reg [DATA_LEN-1:0] out,
  input [KEY_LEN-1:0] key,
  input [DATA_LEN-1:0] default_out,
  input [NR_KEY*(KEY_LEN + DATA_LEN)-1:0] lut
);

  localparam PAIR_LEN = KEY_LEN + DATA_LEN;
  wire [PAIR_LEN-1:0] pair_list [NR_KEY-1:0];
  wire [KEY_LEN-1:0] key_list [NR_KEY-1:0];
  wire [DATA_LEN-1:0] data_list [NR_KEY-1:0];

  genvar n;
  generate
    for (n = 0; n < NR_KEY; n = n + 1) begin
      assign pair_list[n] = lut[PAIR_LEN*(n+1)-1 : PAIR_LEN*n];
      assign data_list[n] = pair_list[n][DATA_LEN-1:0];
      assign key_list[n]  = pair_list[n][PAIR_LEN-1:DATA_LEN];
    end
  endgenerate

  reg [DATA_LEN-1 : 0] lut_out;
  reg hit;
  integer i;
  always @(*) begin
    lut_out = 0;
    hit = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < NR_KEY; i = i + 1) begin
      lut_out = lut_out | ({DATA_LEN{key == key_list[i]}} & data_list[i]);
      hit = hit | (key == key_list[i]);
    end
    if (!HAS_DEFAULT) out = lut_out;
    else out = (hit ? lut_out : default_out);
  end
endmodule
```

This is the c code:

```c
#include "verilated.h"
#include "verilated_vcd_c.h"
#include "VEXU.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

VerilatedContext *contextp = NULL;
VerilatedVcdC *tfp = NULL;
VEXU *top;
using namespace std;

void step_and_dump_wave()
{
  contextp->timeInc(1);
  tfp->dump(contextp->time());
}

void sim_init()
{
  contextp = new VerilatedContext;
  tfp = new VerilatedVcdC;
  top = new VEXU;
  contextp->traceEverOn(true);
  top->trace(tfp, 0);
  tfp->open("dump.vcd");
}

void sim_exit()
{
  step_and_dump_wave();
  tfp->close();
}

void single_cycle()
{
  top->clk = 0;
  top->eval();
  step_and_dump_wave();
  top->clk = 1;
  top->eval();
  step_and_dump_wave();
}

void reset(int n)
{
  top->rst = 1;
  while (n-- > 0)
    single_cycle();
  top->rst = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  sim_init();
  reset(10);

  top->inst = 0x00C000EF;
  single_cycle();
  top->inst = 0xFE9FF0EF;
  single_cycle();

  sim_exit();
  top->final();
}
```

This is Makefile

```
all:
    -@mkdir ./build/
    verilator -MMD --build -cc -O3 --x-assign fast --x-initial fast --assert --trace --coverage \
    --top-module EXU  EXU.v MuxKeyInternal.v MuxKeyWithDefault.v\
    -CFLAGS -DTOP_NAME=EXU -CFLAGS -I/usr/include \
    --Mdir ./build/obj_dir --exe ../main.cpp -o ../EXU
    ./build/EXU
clean:
    @rm -rf ./buil
```

You can run this example, and you'll see the wave like this:
[image]

I want to make key `1FFEF` can hit `key_list[1]`, what should I do?

Comment: Does the answer in [What exactly do x and z values represent in Verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69531332/4207678) help?

Comment: @ChesterGillon I had read the link you posed,  but I actually didn't understand  how to use uncertin value in my case.

Comment: @toolic thanks for your advice , I had add my code.

Comment: @toolic I had post part of my verilator code, but I cann't post my full verilatro code because it's to long.

Comment: @toolic Great thanks for you. I had post a minal example which I have tested in my computer.

Comment: @toolic Thanks for your help. I checked Verilator's docs and I knew that `x` will be replaced by `1` or `0` depending on option `--x-assign`. So I should'nt assgin a `x` to a signal in my situation. And then I mapped these parameters to unique values instead of values with `x`.

Answer (score 0):

I checked [Verilator's docs](https://verilator.org/guide/latest/exe_verilator.html) and I knew that `x`  will be replaced by 1 or 0 depending on option `--x-assign`. So I should'nt assgin a `x` to a signal in my situation. And then I mapped these parameters to unique values instead of values with `x`.

Thanks for everyone who helped me agian.